# The Teacher's Prayer in English

Tags: tefilla, translation

Is there an equivalent or translation in English for the following Teacher's Prayer:[image]

I really need it for my next lesson.

Comment: Where did you get this prayer?

Comment: From a Talmud Tora site, several years ago.

Comment: I have seen loads of different versions of this. There is no one definitive 'prayer'

Comment: I would like to stick as much as possible to the above Nusach. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Let's start from the bottom: https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2619.htm#15

Comment: The last verse is translated to: Let the words of my mouth and the meditation of my heart be acceptable before Thee, O LORD, my Rock, and my Redeemer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent / alternative version (and there are many) that I saw is in Rabbi Yonah Weinrib's כנפי תפילה - Wings of Prayer: A Treasury of Special Prayers and Supplications that is produced by his [Judaica Illuminations](https://judaicailluminations.com/) on p.50-51.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Translation of what you supplied is as follows:

**Teachers Prayer**

My G-d

From you to me I come in prayer,

Give in my heart understanding and the will to learn and teach

To educate the children of the People of Israel

To make them good and upright in the eyes of G-d and man.

---

And I ask again my goodly G-d

Sing to me Your good spirit

That I will not become intolerant, and I will not become angry with their deeds/actions

And give me the strength to bear them/be patient with them with love

And a listening heart to understand them with affection

---

Master of the Universe, strengthen me please

That we don't become slack, that I don't stumble

And will not cause me to bother with the needs of the house nor waste time

On condition that I do the the work of heaven with truth and faith

---

Hashem, show me your way/path

And help me to guide them with the ways of the land (i.e.to be courteous) and the ways of life

To listen, and to learn, to teach and to do

All the words of Your Torah with love and happiness.

---

Let the words of my mouth and the meditation of my heart be acceptable before Thee, O LORD, my Rock, and my Redeemer

Also FYI in case you didn't see it, the first letters of each of the four stanzas spell out מורה - teacher

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm looking for a shorter version. Is there a way to get the English version in text format?

Comment: I'm looking for shorter version (several paragraphs and sentences such as in the attached example). In addition, I look for something that can be used for jews and non-jewish students. Is there a way to get the English content in text format?

Comment: @Avi - please note I have translated what you posted.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! SHANA TOVA!!!!!

Comment: Would it be more correctly to translate the second row in the second paragraph to: Inspire me with Your good spirit

Comment: I guess you can change it to that, I translated it more literally i.e. the etymology I think is similar to the word 'shir' for song